# unable to go from one activity to another

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I try to go from any *activity* to this particular *activity*,
the application goes back to the login screen.

#### Activity (I could not reach) Java source file:

```
package com.example.studentresultmaangementsystem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
importandroid.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class Main7Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button,button1;
    TableLayout layout1;
    TableLayout layout2;
    TableRow table1row1;
    TableRow table1row2;
    TableRow table1row3;
    TableRow table2row1;
    TableRow table2row2;
    TableRow table2row3;
    TableRow table2row4;
    TableRow table2row5;
    TableRow table2row7;
    TableRow table2row6;
    EditText name;
    EditText rollNumber;
    EditText subject1;
    EditText subject2;
    EditText subject3;
    EditText subject4;
    EditText subject5;
    EditText subject6;
    EditText marks1,marks2,marks3,marks4,marks5,marks6;
    DatabaseReference drf;
    Student stu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adding);
        layout1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tb);
        layout2 = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tb2);
        table1row1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.r1);
        table1row2 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.r3);
        table1row3 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row);
        table2row1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row1);
        table2row2 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row2);
        table2row3 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row3);
        table2row4 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row4);
        table2row5 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row5);
        table2row6 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row6);
        table2row7 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row7);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu1);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.en);
        rollNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.er);

        subject1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.es1);
        subject2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.es2);
        subject3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.es3);
        subject4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.es4);
        subject5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.es5);
        subject6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.es6);

        marks1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.em1);
        marks2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.em2);
        marks3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.em3);
        marks4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.em4);
        marks5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.em5);
        marks6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.em6);
        stu = new Student();
        drf = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("student");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String n = name.getText().toString();
                int rollnumber = Integer.parseInt(rollNumber.getText().toString().trim());
                String s1 = subject1.getText().toString();
                String s2 = subject2.getText().toString();
                String s3 = subject3.getText().toString();
                String s4 = subject4.getText().toString();
                String s5 = subject5.getText().toString();
                String s6 = subject6.getText().toString();

                float m1 = Float.parseFloat(marks1.getText().toString().trim());
                float m2 = Float.parseFloat(marks2.getText().toString().trim());
                float m3 = Float.parseFloat(marks3.getText().toString().trim());
                float m4 = Float.parseFloat(marks4.getText().toString().trim());
                float m5 = Float.parseFloat(marks5.getText().toString().trim());
                float m6 = Float.parseFloat(marks6.getText().toString().trim());
                stu.setSubject1(s1);
                stu.setSubject2(s2);
                stu.setSubject3(s3);
                stu.setSubject4(s4);
                stu.setSubject5(s5);
                stu.setSubject6(s6);
                stu.setMarks1(m1);
                stu.setMarks2(m2);
                stu.setMarks3(m3);
                stu.setMarks4(m4);
                stu.setMarks5(m5);
                stu.setMarks6(m6);
                drf.push().setValue(stu);
                Toast.makeText(Main7Activity.this, "the data has been inserted into the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### XML layout file tied to the above Java file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".Main7Activity"
   android:background="#E0314C">

  <TableLayout
     android:id="@+id/tb" android:layout_width="367dp" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp" 
     android:layout_marginVertical="40dp" 
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:background="#f1f1f1" 
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
     tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/r1">

      <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#74B7D5"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="ENTER DETAILS OF STUDENT " android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/r3">

      <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#74B7D5"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text="Name ="
       android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText android:id="@+id/en" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#74B7D5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="RollNo ="
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/er"
        android:layout_width="204dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter rollno"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>


  </TableLayout>


  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tb2"
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="#f1f1f1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tb"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row1">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#74B7D5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Subjects "
        android:textStyle="bold" />


      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#74B7D5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Marks "
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row2">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/es1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" ----------
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="subject_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/em1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter marks"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row3">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/es2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="subject_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/em2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter marks"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row4">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/es3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="subject_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="8"
                
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/em3"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter marks"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row5">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/es4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="subject_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/em4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter marks"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row6">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/es5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="subject_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/em5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter marks"
        android:inputType="number
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row7">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/es6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="subject_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/em6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="enter marks"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>


  </TableLayout>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/bu"
    android:layout_width="106dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="addata"
    android:text="Add data"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.947"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="631dp"
  />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/bu1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="back"
    android:text="Go back"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,OnClick"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="631dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the crash log that you are gettng.

Comment: Formatted question properly and rephrased a bit _(kept dashed line in the middle of the layout snippet because I don't know if this was done on purpose or not)_